# Pyramid get route name by URL (String)

Tags: python, pyramid

I am trying to figure out if its possible to get a route name in Pyramid by the URL (not the Request) URL but a string URL.  So lets say I have a request and the path is /admin/users/manage.  I know you can match the route name to get the route_name of the request but how can I get the route name of /admin and the route name of /admin/users?

```
introspector.get('routes', 'admin')
```

works to get the route path of the admin route but is it possible to work the other way around?

```
introspector.get('routes', 'admin/users')
```

Basically is there a way to get the route_objects of all routes under the admin/ prefix?  Introspector looked like I could loop thru ALL routes but not query all the specific routes within within a path.

Answer (score 2):

I had to dig into the pyramid source code to get this solution.

Also, just to clarify: This solution will provide you with the correct `route_name` for the supplied `route_url`.

If I have `my_route` as the route name and `/foo/bar` as the url, I set the following `my_url` variable to "/foo/bar" and it returns "my_route"

```
from pyramid.interfaces import IRoutesMapper

@view_config(...)
def call_route_by_url(request):
    routes = request.registry.queryUtility(IRoutesMapper).get_routes()
    my_url = '/your/url/here'
    for r in routes:
        if r.path == my_url:
            # do something with r.name <-- that is your route_name
            pass
```